# Given a set of n floating values and k, find number of all possible subsets with sum>=k, k being a floating value

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

This is a variant to the problem :
[Given a set of n integers, list all possible subsets with sum>=k](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18085680/given-a-set-of-n-integers-list-all-possible-subsets-with-sum-k) which is solved using Dynamic Programming.
 Now elements are allowed to be floating type. I thought about using maps in cpp stl instead of DD arrays as now the indices may be floating types. But I am not sure how to loop over the map. Just curious how to approach this one (self-motivated Problem).

EDIT : All numbers can be assumed to be positive.

Comment: Positive @maraca

Comment: The DP solution works **because** the numbers are (bounded) ints. Unbounded floating points don't allow for the same solution, and you'd be left needing an exponential-time algorithm.

Comment: @Dukeling Thats what I said, but how can you prove that it must be exponential time ?

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18085680/given-a-set-of-n-integers-list-all-possible-subsets-with-sum-k The integer approach counts the combinations which sum is smaller than k. So with integers there are max k-1 values in (0,k), but with floating point numbers there is an "infinite" (not really, but a very very large) number of values in (0,k).

Comment: @Akash It might be possible to prove its NP-hardness by reducing [the partition problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem) to it.

Comment: Correct, was thinking in that track myself. Any help appreciated.