# Find maximum number of sets which is satisfied specific condition

Tags: algorithm

Given some set of numbers:

> 156, 434, 600

How to find the maximum number of groups which is over 500? It allows you to make a group with even only one element. But it is not allowed to use an element repeatedly among groups. So, in the above example, the answer is:

> 2 // {156, 434}, {600}

I hope to make a general algorithm can apply it when I get another set of numbers which has difference size.

- 156, 434, 600
- 642, 324, 174, 100, 452
- 174, 100, 455, 900, 1200, 341

But I don't know where should I start to. So, please help me to get a good idea.

Comment: what about the group: {156,334,600} itself which is > 500 so are there 3 answers? {156, 334}, {600} &  {156,334,600}?

Comment: Once used, the numbers cannot be reused? Considering your example we can't, but maximizing the number of groups will result in {600} or {156, 600} or {334, 600} or {156, 334, 600}. Also, why {156, 334} is a valid answer if its sum is 490?

Comment: You don't want this. Because number of groups can be exponential in the size of the input. At least if replacements are allowed.

Comment: you mean that sum of each group needs to be over 500 right>?

Comment: Look at the following post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18085680/given-a-set-of-n-integers-list-all-possible-subsets-with-sum-k

Comment: @valcanaia I'm sorry I miss some limitation and there some input typo error.  I fix my input typo to 434, and add limitation that an element should use only once among groups

Comment: @SamerTufail  I miss some limitation. An element should use only once among groups

Answer (score 0):

One way might be to binary search on the number of bins the best solution, each time using a polynomial-time approximation scheme for the Multiple Subset Sum Problem (such as https://www.researchgate.net/publication/262408639_The_Multiple_Subset_Sum_Problem <sup>1</sup>).

<sub>1. The Multiple Subset Sum Problem; Alberto Caprara, Hans Kellerer and Ulrich Pferschy; 
SIAM Journal on Optimization
Vol. 11: Issue. 2 : Pages. 308-319
(Issue publication date: 2000)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that this problem is NP-Hard. The closest problem I can think of right now is the [bin packing problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem) where you want to minimize the number of bins B (of equal size V) necessary to fit n items of different sizes.

In your case you want to maximize the number of bins, that are minimally filled with a size of V.

As an approximation you could adapt the greedy strategy of the bin packing problem.

```
1) Sort your set of numbers in descending order. 

2) Place all numbers larger than 500 in a seperate group

3) Open a new empty group

4) Find the smallest number that increases the sum of the current open group over 500. 
     If such a number exists, put this number in the current open group jump to 3)
     If no such number exists select the largest number not yet used and place it in the open group and repeat 4)
```

**Example:**

174, 100, 455, 900, 1200, 341

after sorting

1200, 900, 455, 341, 174, 100

resulting groups

{1200}, {900}, {455, 100}, {341, 174}